# c++ issue with variables not being declared in scope error and mismatched types warning

Tags: c++, string, error-handling, scope

I have run into an issue with my program. The basis of the program, in the grand scheme of things, is to read input about a student from files. This includes their name, ID, homework scores and test scores. It is then supposed to calculate all the scores and produce a letter grade. I'm currently only working on printing out the name and ID. My issue is i get errors for all my variables saying they are not declared in this scope. I also get a warning about mismatched types for my string (no idea what that means). Example of not declared in scope error:

```
part1.cpp:38:2: error: ‘infile’ was not declared in this scope
  infile.open (out);
  ^
part1.cpp:38:15: error: ‘out’ was not declared in this scope
  infile.open (out);
```

mismatched types warning:

```
part1.cpp:11:15: note:   mismatched types ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>’ and ‘int’
   outfile <<  name << "  "
               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from part1.cpp:1:
```

here is the overall code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>




void printOutput (std::string name,  std::string Id, float HPfinalscore, float testFinalscore, 
          float overallScore, string LetterGrade, ostream& outfile)
{
  outfile <<  name << "  "
      <<   Id << "  ";
      /*
      << HPfinalscore << "  "
      << testFinalscore << "  "
      << overallScore << "  "
      << LetterGrade;
      */
}



int main()
{
  ofstream outfile;
  ifstream infile; 
  
  int num;
  std::string file_name;
  std::string name; 
  std::string Id;
  std::string LetterGrade;

  float  HPfinalscore = 0, testFinalscore=0, overallScore=0;

    std::cout<<"How many files are you processing: ";
    cin>>num;
    infile.open (out);
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        int count[10];
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            count[i]=0;
          char c,s[1000];
          std::cout<<"Please input the name of the file: ";
          cin>>file_name;
          infile.open(file_name.c_str());
        if ( !infile)
            {
                continue;
                return 0;
            }


            outfile.open("Result");
                if ( !outfile)
                    {
                        std::cout << "Could not open output file \n";
                        return 0;
                    }
    
  

  infile >> name; 
  while(!infile.eof())
    {
      infile >> Id;
      /*
      HPfinalscore = getHPScores(infile); 
      testFinalscore = getTestscores(infile); 
      overallScore = EndingScore(HPfinalscore, testFinalscore); 
      LetterGrade= Grade(overallScore);
    */
    

      printOutput (name, Id, HPfinalscore, testFinalscore, overallScore, 
           LetterGrade, outfile);
      infile >> name; //try to read another name
     
     
    }
  infile.close();
  outfile.close();
  return 0;
}
}
```

So my question is how do I get my variables to be declared correctly? Also any info on the warning and how to handle it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ifstream infile;` should be `std::ifstream infile;` Same for `outfile`.

Comment: you should start with the first error: https://godbolt.org/z/1bdaGTf6f

Comment: You aren't consistent about the `std::`  prefix. `string` should be `std::string` and `ostream` should be `std::ostream` (and what Johnny Mopp said about `ifstream` and `ofstream`).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number wow, definitely bookmarking this site, thank you for sharing it. The site helped me clear all errors except one. I still get the following error on line 37: `part1.cpp:37:18: error: ‘out’ was not declared in this scope
     infile.open (out);
 `

Comment: The argument to `infile.open()` should be a string, but instead is the undeclared variable `out`.

Comment: thats the one where I gave up. What is `out`? It is not declared anywhere

Comment: @ChunkierLizard Your compiler should have given you all those errors. Be sure to read the output from your compiler.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number im really not sure, im mashing multiple labs together to make a project and I think I confused myself along the way and I have no Idea what is supposed to replace out.

Comment: frankly, that way of writing code can only result in a mess. Don't write code that you do not understand. There are just too many things that can go wrong

Comment: @jjramsey what string would take the place of out? Would it be the input file name as the out?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the documentation for the `open()` member function: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ifstream, ostream, and ofstream to std::ifstream, std::ostream, and std::ofstream. Also, get rid of this line:

```
infile.open(out);
```